# Optimize Bulk drawing using Canvas

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a text file with a X and Y Coordinates that maps to a Bitmap that contains all the tiles to be drawns using Grid Coordinates onto the screen using the method.

`Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, Rect, Paint);`

I am afraid that by using this method in a thread i will be Overrun by Garbage Collecting from all the Rect instantiations reducing performance.

I have checked to see if the Tiles I'm drawing are first within my frame which helps performance a bit, but is there anything else i can do to avoid performance issues (primary worry is the GC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really that worried about it, you could just have two Rect objects and use [`public void set (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) to change the values, and have them as member variables in the class to keep the GC from deleting them.

Comment: P.S. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming" -Donald Knuth (this quote has changed my life, though in your case, it was a pretty good idea)

Comment: Wow cant believe i didn't see that method in the Rect class...shows me for not reading into it! Thanks!

Comment: Haha, story of my life.